# MPI Gather and qsort

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to do a simple sort, where every non-zero proc reads a file (filename = proc#) into a buffer. The zero proc gathers all these bufs, sorts it and then prints it out. However, in the following code, proc 0 gathers proc1's buffer, but not proc 2's.  Any suggestions?

I execute it with mpirun -np 3 a.out

my input files are
Filename: "1"
40
10
100

Filename: "2"
90
20
25

and code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define DEBUG 1

//#undef DEBUG


int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int values[3];
int recv[3];
int n, i=0, temp;
FILE *in1, *in2;
int rank, size;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
char filename[20];
if(rank!=0){
      // read files with filename"<proc#>" into the buffer
      sprintf(filename, "%d", rank);
      in1=fopen(filename,"r");
      while(fscanf(in1,"%d",&values[i]) != EOF){
            printf("rank %d Read data %d\n", rank,values[i]);
            i++;
      }
 }
 // gather values from all procs.

 MPI_Gather(values,i,MPI_INT,recv,i,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 printf("Gather done!");
if(rank==0){


    // sort
    qsort (recv, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
    // print results
    for (n=0; n<6; n++)
            printf ("%d ",recv[n]);
    printf("\n");
 }

 if(rank!=0)
    fclose(in1);
 MPI_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: i edited my answer. I think receiver buffer size should be 9 , check with this now...

Answer (score 2):

```
int recv[3];
```

size of receiving buffer should be the total number of elements from all the processors to be gathered on the gathering node.
so recv[9] should work here.

checkout this example for gather
[example](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node70.htm)